# Eclipse plugin version loading

Tags: eclipse

I want to know how eclipse load the plugins. I have plugin with two different version say(1.1.0 and 1.2.0). Which plugin eclipse loads at runtime? If the old plugin(1.1.0), then what configuration we need to add in order to load latest plugin(If their are many)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383880/loading-same-plugin-twice-with-different-version-in-eclipse

Comment: Eclipse is supposed to load the newest version of a plug-in.  You can check by looking at the Help -> About Eclipse and left clicking on the Installation Details button.